# How do I make sure that Canonical get affiliate benefits when I buy from amazon?

Tags: canonical, shopping-lens

Ubuntu 12.10 has a new feature to search and buy from Amazon, either from the Dash, or from a unity WebApp. This is quite controversial, but for my part, I quite ok with it. So when I buy something from Amazon (which I did before, and I'll do tomorow), I'd like to make sure the affiliate revenue are really given to Ubuntu/Canonical: I would have bought anyway, so financing my prefered OS by doing so makes sense to me.

How does it work, and how can I know my order get accounted to Ubuntu/Canonical affiliate program ? What if I navigate the amazon site before I buy ? What if I login or logout from Amazon, does Ubuntu still benefit from my order ?

Comment: Great thought. The few items offered in the Dash are not really those I always wanted to buy but I'd be happy to see some Cents going to Canonical everytime I make an Amazon order.

Comment: Its a good question. I have just been playing with the new Amazon app in 12.10 and it takes me to the Amazon.com site, but I live in Ireland and 90% of my purchases are via Amazon.co.uk. That said, living in Ireland you have to manage your Kindle and purchase Kindle books via the Amazon.com website! So would like to know what the 'best practice' is to make make sure Canonical get some benefits.

Comment: You might also want to directly [donate](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/contribute) to Ubuntu, this method having the added benefit of letting you choose into *which* areas of development your money goes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all note that it's not just Amazon. It's a shopping lens, which can be used for numerous backend stores, of which Amazon is one.

The Amazon affiliate referral happens if you've arrived at the Amazon property via a 'tagged' link. Both links clicked via the dash which go to Amazon sites, and the shortcut in the launcher will add the tag. The tag adds a cookie which lasts for 24 hours. If you buy anything during that period, Canonical will get some affiliate revenue.

Personally I've just "pinned" a tab in my browser (i.e. opened whenever I open the browser) which goes to http://www.amazon.co.uk/?tag=u1webapp-uk-21 (which is right for the UK, but will differ for other territories) which ensures the cookie is always there for me. So even if I don't follow links via the dash or use the launcher, I still give revenue to Canonical (my employer ;) ).

- For the US: http://www.amazon.com/?tag=u1webapp-20
- For Canada: http://www.amazon.ca/?tag=u1webapp-ca-20
- For Germany: http://amazon.de/?tag=u1webapp-21

I also do this on 12.04 where I don't have the shopping lens installed.

Comment: Cool... then I can get rid of shopping lens, which I really find intrusive, and still support Canonical... Even better, can I add the tag on my wifes Macbook, and still support Canonical ?

Comment: Tag here looks like this: tag=u1treatyrslf-fr-21  I guess the treatyrslf part mean I used the dash...

Comment: What is the tag for Amazon in the U.S.? I'd like to support Canonical from within 12.04.

Comment: what if I am using amazon.it?

Comment: I guess the correct question to ask would be, how do I find out the correct ref link for my country?

Comment: Can you please update your answer with info on the German link? It is http://amazon.de/?tag=u1webapp-21