# What is the German Amazon affiliate link for Canonical?

Tags: 14.04, canonical

Found this: [How do I make sure that Canonical get affiliate benefits when I buy from amazon?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/192725/how-do-i-make-sure-that-canonical-get-affiliate-benefits-when-i-buy-from-amazon)

But is there also a German one?